# Generate several Comboboxes in WPF Based on DataTable List

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate

I want to create dynamic comboboxes based on a list of datatables. 
Every time I  add a new datatable to the list I want the UI to generate a new combobox which displays the column I specify from the table. I tried it with a itemscontrol and datatemplate but doesn't work like I want.

```
public List<DataTable> DtList
    {
        get { return dtList; }
        set { dtList = value; }
    }


<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DtList}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
          <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox 
                          VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                          Margin="0,0,4,10"
                          Width="200"
                          BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ListBox.Static.Border}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding DataSet}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Element Name"
                          SelectedValuePath="ResourceType Name"
                          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedRelationPath, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                          />
          </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just created a sample and it's working for me

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
          //  this.DataContext = this; Uncomment this if code behind is your datacontext
            InitializeComponent();
            DataTable t1 = new DataTable();
            t1.Columns.Add("Name");
            t1.Columns.Add("Age");
            t1.Rows.Add("A", "1");
            t1.Rows.Add("B", "2");
            DataTable t2 = new DataTable();
            t2.Columns.Add("Name");
            t2.Columns.Add("Age");
            t2.Rows.Add("A", "1");
            DtList = new List<DataTable> { t1, t2 };
        }
        private List<DataTable> dtList;
        public List<DataTable> DtList
        {
            get { return dtList; }
            set
            {
                dtList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DtList");
            }
        }
        private string selectedName;
        public string SelectedName
        {
           get { return selectedName; }
           set
           {
              selectedName = value;
              OnPropertyChanged("SelectedName");
           }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler == null) return;
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

In your Xaml add this in your window or UserControl tag

```
x:Name="windowName"
```

Now do this

```
<StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DtList}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox 
                          VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                          Margin="0,0,4,10"
                          Width="200"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                          SelectedValuePath="Age" 
                          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedName,ElementName=windowName}"
                          />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: Thanksk now it's working for me do you know why Selected Value can't find the properties in my class it now shows only the properties of datatable class

Comment: In this case, you've multiple combo boxes. Do you need to bind the selected value of each combo box to each property or All Combobox selected value to a single property?

Comment: to a single one

Comment: I've edited the code Take a look. Upvote if you get it right.

Comment: still can't access to my property

Comment: I've made 3 changes from previous 1-> (x:Name="windowName") add this in your xaml,most base user control/window tag you are using  2->  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedName,ElementName=windowName}" Add this in Combobox Tag 3->  private string selectedName;
        public string SelectedName
      {
         get { return selectedName; }
         set
         {
            selectedName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedName");
          }
        }  Add this in code if you want to then put a break point in the setter of SelectedName property and select from combobox.

Comment: Do all these 3 and you'll get the hit on the breakpoint I've tried this before posting.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have wrong binding for combobox items. Is there any wpf binding errors in the VS output window when you open the form under debug?

you have bound `ItemsControl` to the `DtList` property. It is fine and for each item in the list combobox should be created. Do you have comboboxes created for each record in the `DtList` at runtime?

However the combobox item binding does not look correct for me. Each combobox is getting `DtList` item as data context. But you have bound it like `ItemsSource="{Binding DataSet}"`. This makes combobox to read items from the  `DataTable.DataSet` property.

Please try change combobox items binding like `ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}"`

Comment: Edited it like you said still doesnt work no comboboxes are generated

Comment: please check that you have certain items in the `DtList` list. Add new control (like listbox) and bind  its items source to check that you have list filled with items `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DtList}"`. You should use `ObservableCollection<DataTable> DtList` in the view model class if tables are loaded after form was shown (like when button is clicked)